# Count merged cells that have substring

Tags: excel, vba

I have some code by a former coworker that counts merged cells with a particular string. For example, if there was a merged cell with size 3 with the name "Youtube" on it, it would return 3.

This is the function in question:

```
Function MergedCellsCount(rRange As Range, crit As Variant) As Double
Application.Volatile
MergedCellsCount = 0 'in case there are no matches
    
For Each c In rRange
    If LCase(c.Value) = LCase(crit) Then
        MergedCellsCount = MergedCellsCount + c.MergeArea.Cells.Count
        prev_rng = c.MergeArea.Address
    End If
Next
 
' MergedCellsCount = MergedCellsCount / 5
End Function
```

But now, i want to count the cells that have a substring within that string.
If for example there was a merged cell with size 3 with "Youtube | Spotify", I want to know how to change that function to search for the substring "Youtube".

Any suggestions on how to achieve this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Count Cells Containing a String (Merged Cells) (UDF)

- Note that if you merge or unmerge cells within the Criteria Range, the cells count will not be updated until the next recalculation of the worksheet.
- To trigger recalculation, a nice 'trick' is to autofit a column by double clicking the right border of its column header (e.g. for column `A`, the short line between `A` and `B`).

**The Code**

```
Option Explicit

Function MergedCellsCount(CriteriaRange As Range, _
                          Criteria As String) _
         As Long
    Application.Volatile
    Dim c As Range
    For Each c In CriteriaRange.Cells
        If Not IsError(c) Then
            If InStr(1, c.Value, Criteria, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
                MergedCellsCount = MergedCellsCount + c.MergeArea.Cells.Count
            End If
        End If
    Next
End Function
```